# How to manually trigger flush execution to clean the data under wal directory?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I know that Apache IoTDB can use `flush` to clean the data under `wal` directory, and this `flush` execution can automatically be operated by the system. I want to know how often this `flush` execution is operated, and can IoTDB manually trigger `wal` data flush? If it can be manually triggered, which configuration should I set, or what command can I execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manually trigger the `flush` operation of `wal` directory in Apache IoTDB, you can execute `start-cli.sh -e flush` in the Cli tool of IoTDB.
The automatic `flush` operation will be executed based on the size of `wal` directory. However, you can also set the timing of triggering `flush` operation by modifying the `seq_memtable_flush_interval_in_ms` and `unseq_memtable_flush_interval_in_ms` configuration in `iotdb-common.properties` directory. The default timing is 3 hours.